# Registered Server list and groups disappeared from SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I recently installed SQL Server 2012. Due to some issue, the databases services did not install successfully, but Management Studio did, which was OK to start with, as I usually access remote servers.

I imported my groups of servers and worked happily.

Yesterday, I restarted my PC, and lo and behold, the list of groups and server is not there at all - all I have is an empty Object Explorer without any way to access my saved server and connect. See Screenshot below.

Through `File > Connect Object Explorer` I get the dialog where I can open what is listed there  but that's a pain, as I had many servers listed there and it was very user-friednly to have them listed and grouped nicely.

So my question is how can I get them listed there again.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list you're talking about wouldn't be present in Object Explorer (unless you connected to all of them manually every time you started Management Studio). Your active connections will disappear from Object Explorer when you close down SSMS or reboot, so you can't persist them there (as convenient as that might be).

What you might be talking about, though, is Registered Servers, which you might have inadvertently closed before closing SSMS last (it should pop up again if it was active when you shut down SSMS or rebooted). If it's missing, no problem, you can restore this panel using `View > Registered Servers` or through the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

If your servers still don't show up there, it's possible that you lost your registered server configuration due to a roaming profile, logging in as a different user, or messing with SqlStudio.bin.

Comment: How do I have the "Local Server Groups" section in "Registered Servers" expanded by default when I start ssms? I have to expand them manually every time.

Comment: @AndersLindén I don't know that there's any way to do that, aside from filing a feature request on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/sql), or just not closing and re-opening SSMS so often (also a solution for slow app startup).